# Extend table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding extending a table in mysql.

Let's assume that we have a user table

User:
user_id
user_name

Let's assume that this is user is used in a company which has multiple departments.
Now if the HR department want the user to have birthday and hire date fields only, but finance department needs the bank account id and years of service fields only.

I think I need to have another table, but I don't know how will it look like.
How can I make the table flexible in a way that it can be extended based on the needs?

Comment: Put all columns into the same table of user metadata.  If your company really wants a firewall between departments, then you could create separate tables for each.

Comment: Years of service can probably be calculated from hire date. It is possible that more than one bank account id may be needed for a user anyway; some employers allow splitting direct deposits into multiple accounts. But in a more general sense, you should rely on your UI/client code to filter out data not relevant rather than partitioning your based on "views".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the thing is, it's not fixed, let's say that the HR now wants 2 fields, but they could add more fields from the UI, that's why I need it flexible, I want them to be able to add columns but when the department adds a column, it will be visible only by them.

Comment: Which fields you display or don't display is an application-level concern. Having separate tables to enforce permissions is a bad plan. Permissions change in arbitrary ways and having full control over the display logic in your application layer is important.

Comment: This is probably a legitimate case for Views. Adding columns should be a task for the dba. If departments regularly need to modify structure, that points towards bad design